# Time series graphing

Tags: r, time, time-series

I am having issues to plot my time series data.
The graph is not showing and I have some errors.
I need assistance in the code or data. I don't know why it's not working

Use R

For this attached time series data set in the link below (SP500 index) :

https://www.kaggle.com/code/andrewmvd/s-p-500-analysis-crawler

Plot your time series data with time on the horizontal axis.
Add a horizontal time as the sample mean.
Add a simple linear regression trend line with time as the independent variable.
Add a moving average of three to your plot.

Plot the ACF for your time series.
Indicate if the ACF cuts off (and when) or if it trails off.

Plot the PACF for your time series.
Indicate if the PACF cuts off (and when) or if it trails off.

Answer :

## Load the data

```
 library(tidyverse)
 sp500 <- read.csv("SP500.csv")
 head(sp500)
```

Date

close

1   2/4/13  1496
2   2/5/13  1511
3   2/6/13  1512
4   2/7/13  1509
5   2/8/13  1518
6   2/11/13 1517

## Plot time series data

```
 ggplot(sp500, aes(x = Date, y = Close)) +
 geom_line() +
 geom_hline(yintercept = mean(sp500$Close), linetype = "dashed") +
 geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
 geom_line(stat = "rolling_mean", window = 3, linetype = "dotted") +
 xlab("Date") +
 ylab("Close")
```

## Plot ACF

```
library(forecast)
 acf(sp500$Close)
```

## Plot PACF

```
 pacf(sp500$Close)
```

Comment: "The graph is not showing and I have some errors." What errors? After which lines of code?

Comment: The link is a 404 error for me. Can you share some of the data you have? (easiest by running dput(head(sp500)) and pasting all the output into your question. That will produce code that generates the first 6 rows of your data.)

Comment: Description:df [6 × 2]
 
 
Date
<chr>
close
<dbl>
1 2/4/13 1496  
2 2/5/13 1511  
3 2/6/13 1512  
4 2/7/13 1509  
5 2/8/13 1518  
6 2/11/13 1517

Comment: I have added the head for the data

Comment: It'll be easier to help if you can run the code `dput(head(sp500))` and paste the output into the body of your question.

Comment: It looks like one of the issues is that your dates are loaded as character data. Unlike Excel, R doesn't typically treat values as dates until you tell it to. For the moment, R is treating those values like a category, like "orange," and any calculations or plotting won't treat the dates as dates. Try ` sp500 <- read.csv("SP500.csv") |> mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%y"))`

Comment: Thank you. It works now. One last problem I am having is with the moving average. I am getting this error                                                                               " Error in geom_moving_average(data = sp500, aes(y = close), n = 3, color = "green") : 
  could not find function "geom_moving_average"

Comment: I am having this error with the moving average : "Error in check_subclass(stat, "Stat", env = parent.frame()) : "

Comment: I tried also this line " geom_moving_average(aes(y = close), n = 3, color = "green") "  I am having error " Error in geom_moving_average(data = sp500, aes(y = close), n = 3, color = "green") : could not find function "geom_moving_average"